# Using empty over == ""

Tags: php

It has come to my attention, that using `if (empty($var)){` is not as efficient as most people like to think.

Rather using `empty()` I have been using if `($Var == ""){`

because if the textbox/input has a whitespace, it is not empty.. Whereas using `==""` doesn't notice whitespaces, so if there is a whitespace, and only a white space, my second example is more efficient

is this a bug in php?

Comment: Worrying about PHP micro-optimizations is not a good allocation of your precious time.  You're better than that.

Comment: Seems like `trim($Var) == ""` would work for you.  `empty()` also tests if a variable is defined

Comment: `empty` also deals with the case where the variable isn't set, which is fairly common.

Comment: False premise:
`php -r "echo (' '=='' ? 'true' : 'false');"
false`

Comment: There is a bug in **your** code. `" "` is not equal to `""` and `" "` is not empty.

Comment: This should clear things up: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: you spent more time typing the question than will be saved in many years of your code running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP documentation for [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

It looks like you are just testing if there is a non whitespace character and so this should work:

```
 if (strlen(trim($var)) == 0)
```

Comment: I use empty by default, but have to switch to isset if expecting a 0

Answer (score 0):

From [function.empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) manual's page.

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

And `empty(" ")` returns `FALSE`.

In addition, the `" "` string is same as ASCII character `0x20`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug in PHP. All languages improve themselves little by little. There are many functions that PHP claims , they are depreciated at the future. is this mean ...they have bugs?
By the way , i think `is_null($var)` is near to what you need.

Edit 2:

There is a good link for difference between empty(),is_null() and isset()

http://mechiwiki.com/techmed/php/php-empty-is_null-and-isset-comparison

Comment: His question about `empty($var)` and `if ($Var == "")`... i tried to introduce him a better function.

Comment: `is_null($var)` would only return true if `$var` is null.  If set-but-blank is a likely state, `empty` is probably better.